# Can you use CSS transitions on SVG attributes? Like y2 on a line?

Tags: css, svg, reactjs

I want to change the attributes of an SVG line, and animate the transition to the new coordinates.

I am using reactjs to change the value of y2 in this example:

```
<line stroke='green' x1='0' y1='50%' x2='100%' y2='25%'>
```

to

```
<line stroke='green' x1='0' y1='50%' x2='100%' y2='75%'>
```

with CSS like

```
.myStuff * {
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

**Is it possible for a CSS transition to work on the y2 attribute?** Or is there a way to set the attributes of the line in CSS like:

```
.myStuff line {
    y2: 25%;
}
```

*(which I know doesn't work)*

I have considered using javascript, but that adds complexity

I have considered using SMIL, but I would have to store the old and new y2 states, and I don't think reactjs allows the animate element.

I have considered using a transform on my line element, and will go down this path if I can't find a better solution. I want to avoid the math and complexity.

Comment: In SVG 2 you can, in SVG 1.1 you can't. Only Chrome/Opera supports this part of SVG 2 so far.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks. How do you do it in SVG2?  Any examples?

Comment: Per the syntax you already have. If it doesn't work maybe no UA has implemented it yet. Firefox, IE and Safari certainly haven't.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle to test out browsers: https://jsfiddle.net/odfo6vov/ Not even working in Chrome :(

Comment: Note: SVG2 hasn't yet made x1, x2, y1, y2 presentation attributes, see https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/geometry.html. I think WebKit(Safari) was first to support x, y, width, height, cx, cy, rx, ry, and r as properties, and with Blink(Chrome/Opera) being second.

Comment: The only you can do for now is using stroke-dasharray, but you have to know the size of your line. stroke-dasharray is transitionable.

Answer (score 3):

Using *JQuery* `.attr()` changes `"y2"` to `"75%"` like you see in [**fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/yqvskxq4/2/)

But the hard part is you want to use `transition`.

In this case you have to use `transform:matrix()`:

HTML:

```
<svg height="300" width="300">
  <line class="first" stroke='green' x1='0' y1='50%' x2='100%' y2='25%'/>
</svg>

<button id="change">change</button>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#button").click(function(){
      $(".first").css({
                    "transform":"matrix(1, 0.6, 0, 1, 0, 0)",
                    "-webkit-transform":"matrix(1, 0.6, 0, 1, 0, 0)",
                    "-ms-transform":"matrix(1, 0.6, 0, 1, 0, 0)"
     });
   });    
});
```

CSS:

```
.first
{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

See a working **[fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/yqvskxq4/4/)**.

***The tip is using some numbers in `matrix()` which provides your result.***