# How can I change the 'd' attribute of a path with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Beginner in JS & HTML, Want to change some parameters with the console from an existing website.

The code I want to change looks like the following. It's a path in the form of a circle and I want to change the d Parameter in a way, that it slowly grows and turns into a circle. I also added my own id="stroke1", so I can get to that specific Element (I can't address the class because there are more Elements on the website)

```
<path stroke="LightGray" class="ng-tns-c172-3 ng-star-inserted" 
d="M-113.92397275527559,-117.97172725553874A164,164,0,0,1,2.95405778773832,
-163.97339278854574L2.5469886245879794,-141.37785926228415A141.4008,141.4008,
0,0,0,-98.22524930959861,-101.7152232397255Z" 
fill="#008DD2" id="stroke1"></path>
```

My attempt to get the d parameter is the following.

```
document.getElementById('stroke1').getAttribute('d');
```

Now, I would like to write a loop to increase this path.

Something like

```
for(i=0; i<100; i++) { 
 document.getElementById('stroke1').getAttribute('d)' // increase the path somehow with + i
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: The phrasing of “increase the path” makes rather little sense. Please explain how _exactly_ you want to modify the existing path here. Do you want to change the values of the points already existing in the given path, do you want to add points at the end, …?

Comment: Ah, sorry for that! I attached a screenshot of the webpage. I would like to change the path in a way that it grows and fills the area here

https://imgur.com/a/jruccEu

Comment: For that, it might perhaps make more sense, if you followed this kind of approach: https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/

Comment: If you're just asking how to set the attribute value, see [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute). Otherwise, please revise to be more specific.

Comment: This looks like a similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32729752/css-transition-animation-doesnt-work-on-svg-paths-d-attribute-change/32730094

Comment: thanks for all the comments! You were right, I used setAttribute, and it worked.The only problem I have left is, that increasing some values with +i doesn't result into a circle.
I used this code
```
document.getElementById('stroke1').setAttribute('d', 'M-113.92397275527559,-117.97172725553874A164,164,0,0,1,-73.53232053595076,
-146.59126111947532L-63.39956676609675,
-126.39098533721162A141.4008, 141.4008, 0, 0, 0, -98.22524930959861,-101.7152232397255Z')
```
I know that I have tho change the numbers
-73.5..,
-146.5...,
-126.3...,
but it get's destroyed when I increase it

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0; i<100; i++) {
    const stroke = document.getElementById('stroke1');
    const d = stroke.getAttribute('d'); // increase the path somehow with + i
    stroke.setAttribute('d', d + i);
}
```