# Change d-attribute of SVG Path

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <button onclick="change_line_d()">Change Line</button>
<div id="main-container" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; border:1px solid #DA096C;">
  <svg id="svg-id" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: inline; width: inherit; min-width: inherit; max-width: inherit; height: inherit; min-height: inherit; max-height: inherit;" version="1.1">   
    <path data-key="12345" id="path_id_1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,600)" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 124.34 185.57 L 154.34 200 L 135.22 250 "/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

In my SVG path, is there a way to **change the d-attribute** for each svg path using the **path_id,** for example, I wish to click on a button and it will change the d-path to

```
d="M 164.34 115.57 L 194.34 280 L 131.22 280 L 111.22 980 "/>
```

May I know if there is a way to do this? Any help will be very much appreciated :)

Someone asked a question quite similar to mine at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66441633/how-can-i-change-the-d-attribute-of-a-path-with-javascript), but I am unsure on how to implement it in my code

Comment: Just select the path and change the `d`attribute via `setAttribute()` like so `path_id_1.setAttribute('d', 'M 164.34 115.57 L 194.34 280 L 131.22 280 L 111.22 980')`

Answer (score 1):

The great thing about inline SVG is the fact that we can easily access all its attributes from the DOM. Since you've elected to inline the SVG instead of linking it with a img tag we can skip the more tedious process of importing it into the DOM and go straight to accessing its properties. This function will change the path. Not much to explain here it is straight forward. select the element with getElementById and change its "d" attribute with setAttribute.

```js
function change_line_d(){
    document.getElementById("path_id_1")
    .setAttribute("d","M 164.34 115.57 L 194.34 280 L 131.22 280 L 111.22 980 ")
}
```

```html
<button onclick="change_line_d()">Change Line</button>
<div id="main-container" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; border:1px solid #DA096C;">
    <svg id="svg-id" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: inline; width: inherit; min-width: inherit; max-width: inherit; height: inherit; min-height: inherit; max-height: inherit;" version="1.1">   
        <path data-key="12345" id="path_id_1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,600)" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 124.34 185.57 L 154.34 200 L 135.22 250 "/>
    </svg>
</div>
```