# Convert SVG SMIL attribute animation to CSS

Tags: svg

As SVG SMIL animations are being deprecated, I'm trying to convert some shape morphing animation to CSS3 keyframe animations. Most conversions are straight forward, except for the ones where I'm using the path attribute `d=`.

For example, this SVG morphs between 3 (actually 4, but the beginning/end are equal) stages:

```
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 9 3">
    <path fill="#2ECC71" d="M0 9h9V0L0 0">
      <animate attributeName="d" 
               values="M0 9h9V0L0 0; M0 9h9V0L1 0; M0 9h9V0L1 1; M0 9h9V0L0 0"
               repeatCount="indefinite"
               calcMode="spline"
               keySplines=".75 .1 .25 .9; .75 .1 .25 .9; .75 .1 .25 .9" 
               keyTimes="0; .33; .66; 1"
               dur="10s" />
    </path>
  </svg>
```

My (rather optimistic) conversion to `@keyframes` looks like

```
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 9 3">
    <defs>
      <style type="text/css">
        @keyframes anima {
          0% {
            d: M0 9h9V0L0 0;
          }
          33% {
            d: M0 9h9V0L1 0;
          }
          66% {
            d: M0 9h9V0L1 1;
          }
          100% {
            d: M0 9h9V0L0 0;
          }
        }

        #a {
          animation: anima 10s ease-in-out infinite;
        fill: #22A7F0;
        }
      </style>
    </defs>
    <path id="a" d="M0 9h9V0L0 0" />
  </svg>
```

While this does draw the initial shape, there is no animation. The only browser providing a clue is Firefox which mentions: `Unknown property 'd'. Declaration dropped.`. This makes sense, though I cannot seem to figure out how to declare a morphing shape without using SMIL.

Obligatory demonstration [can be found on Codepen](http://codepen.io/foozle/pen/rxjMYK?editors=100)

I'd like to keep the SVG standalone, so javascript is not an option if it can be avoided (as I'm using the SVG as a background image).
As tempting as it may seem for this example, I am also trying to avoid using `CSS transforms` as the SVG I'm converting consist of various shapes morphing together.

Comment: [SMIL isn't deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/animate.html#RelationshipToSMILAnimation), at least not yet. There are js libraries to implement SMIL in browsers that don't or won't support it. Also, CSS can't animate the `d` attribute, see [the list of currently shared attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#SVGStylingProperties). [here is a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075830/) where @ErikDahlström points to the fact that "SVG2 hasn't yet made x1, x2, y1, y2 presentation attributes, see https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/geometry.html ". `d` isn't either.

Comment: I am aware that SMIL is still in the specs, it's just that Chrome (as of v45) has a console warning `SVG's SMIL animations (<animate>, <set>, etc.) are deprecated and will be removed. Please use CSS animations or Web animations instead.`
This is what triggered me to convert the SMIL animations to CSS3, which works fine for most transforms or with a little added javascript, though obviously this will not work in the use-case of SVG as background image.

Comment: I didn't even know webkit do support SMIL and css animations in background-image, FF doesn't ... For the chrome deprecation of SMIL, they're alone in there (except Blink but because they still don't support it) , other browsers continue to support and develop it. Also, CSS won't ever be able to replace SMIL, and unfortunately, there is still no real tool able to do path transformations as SMIL, maybe you could try gif ? (kidding)

Comment: For now I'll just settle for the SMIL version and made sure it renders ok if it really is deprecated by the Chrome team (had to do that anyway as IE doesn't support it at all). Funny thing about Firefox is that one of the animations does work, but others don't, haven't been able to figure out why that is and at this point, it doesn't really matter. Thanks for commenting though!

Comment: And if image-background is not your only use-case, then you should definitely try [fakesmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/) which was made for IE and [this polyfill](https://github.com/ericwilligers/svg-animation) which is recommended by Blink in their [intent for deprecation message](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/5o0yiO440LM[1-25])