# How can I animate/use transition to crop the length of a svg-line?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

If we have a background and a foreground line, using the same dash-array, we can set the x2 value of the 2nd to get a progress-bar looking image.

```
<svg width="1000" height="40">
    <g stroke-width="40" stroke-dasharray="0 5 90 5">
        <line stroke="gray" x1="0" x2="1000" y1="20" y2="20" />
        <line stroke="green" x1="0" x2="750" y1="20" y2="20" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

But if we change the x2 value, it change size directly, it isn't animated with the css `transition: all 0.30s;`

Played around with clippath, transform-scale, transform-translate, but can't get it to animate it.

A setInterval may solve it, but would rather have a css soultion.
Can it be done?

Comment: Use SMIL to animate it.

Comment: @RobertLongson Chrome [deprecated](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?revision=196823&view=revision) SMIL.

Comment: So what, you can use https://github.com/ericwilligers/svg-animation to reenable it.

Comment: @RobertLongson if I need a javascript-library to get it working, I think i prefer the setInterval() better.

Comment: Perhaps this answer transforming matrices might lead to a solution for you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/34815484/5285945 (I tried a go at making a fiddle for your example, but the matrix stuff makes my head hurt too much).